# Day-night mode separate wallpapers

Tags: desktop-environments, desktop-background, 22.10

In some way I had two separate wallpapers for Night and Day modes respectively. After I've decided to change the wallpaper I cannot grasp how to return the separate wallpapers feature. Can you help me to figure out how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: But it worked for me in other way. The wallpapers switched dependent on which mode I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have understood how I'd managed to have two separate wallpapers one for a day and one for a night.

Unlike Fedora, in which you can set separate wallpapers for day and night modes respectively, Ubuntu 22.10 does not have this feature (maybe, it's a bug?). But there is a simple way to have two different wallpapers at once.
Let us use gThumb - one of the greatest image viewers and image organizers.
There are 2 steps to our goal:

1. Set the night wallpaper via "Change background" menu item.
2. Set the day wallpaper using gThumb.

Done. Now your wallpapers are changed according to chosen theme.

How does it works. If you set the wallpaper from gThumb it sets only the day wallpaper. So the previous wallpaper stays valid for the night mode of you desktop.

Comment: I have made a video with an example https://youtu.be/35qvFOpQ84M